# Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. invalid stream or object version change

Tags: c#

I know like this question is existed but they not help to me, I want post a file of an action to ConvertToFLV action then that return an object converted to byte[], now when I want convert it to object I get The following error in ByteArrayToObject method, when reach to this line Video obj = (Video)binForm.Deserialize(memStream)
Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
In addition please tell me contentType is correct in ConvertToFLV action?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:25220/home/ConvertToFLV");
            request.Method = "POST";
            string path = Request.MapPath("~") + "2.wmv";
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] convertedBytes = new byte[(int)response.ContentLength];
            dataStream.Read(convertedBytes, 0, (int)response.ContentLength);
            var obj = ByteArrayToObject(convertedBytes);
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return View();
        }
public FileResult ConvertToFLV(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            Stream stream = HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
            byte[] result = new byte[HttpContext.Request.ContentLength];
            stream.Read(result, 0, HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);
            Video video = new Video { FLV = result };
            return File(ObjectToByteArray(video), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }
 private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Video obj = (Video)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            return obj;
        }

    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Video obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```